# Installing toastr in an AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, toastr

Have been trying to use toastr in my AngularJS app:

```
app.module("MyApp", ['toastr']);
```

But it doesn't work, the module toastr can not be found! I thought toastr were a AngularJS module?

Anyone who knows how to load the module, or if there are any Angular-directives I can use?

Comment: Are you sure that the module is loaded? `<script type="text/javascript" src="angular-toastr.tpls.js"></script>`

Comment: What's the instantiation of `app` look like? It's hard to tell from the lack of code how you're instantiating `app`.

Answer (score 5):

Without seeing the instantiation of `app`, in your example, there's no way for me to know if you're actually loading your dependencies correctly; so I'll take you through the steps to load it from scratch (Source: [here](https://github.com/Foxandxss/angular-toastr)).

There are a few things you have to do to get toastr working on AngularJS:

1. Download the [angular-toastr distribution](https://github.com/Foxandxss/angular-toastr/releases).
2. add the following to your index.html (effectively wherever you're loading all your scripts):

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="angular-toastr.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-toastr.tpls.js"></script>`

3. Add toastr to the app's modules (not each controller, or a service. Add it to the app). Your `app.js` file:

`angular.module('myApp', ['toastr'])`.

Comment: I've tried exactly what you've written above, but am still having no luck. Still getting an injector error, see screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/karwq1v9e498i7v/Screenshot%202015-10-01%2014.05.48.png?dl=0 Any idea why?

Comment: ha, it might have had something to do with my using toastr.js and not angular.toastr.js. Whoops!

Answer (score 2):

No, toastr is not an Angular module. There are various ports of toastr to Angular including [angular-toastr](https://github.com/Foxandxss/angular-toastr) or [AngularJS-Toaster](https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to inject it as a dependency unless you are using angular port of toastr (eg: angular-toastr). For the original toastr, just including the .js and .css, and should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add `toastr` as a dependency in your module. You just need to include `toastr.js` and `toastr.css` files in your project and you can then `toastr` like this

```
toastr.success("This is a success message");
```